# Como salvar dados de uma coluna para depois sobrescrevê-los novamente? SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Preciso salvar os dados de uma tabela para um comando no banco e voltar esses dados para a mesma tabela depois de um tempo...

[image: Dados que precisam ser salvos]

Pensei em fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
DECLARE @NOME_FILIAL VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE @DATA_AJUSTE DATETIME;
DECLARE @CODIGO_FILIAL CHAR(6) = '300135';

    SET @NOME_FILIAL = (SELECT FILIAL FROM FILIAIS WHERE COD_FILIAL = @CODIGO_FILIAL);

    SET @DATA_AJUSTE = (SELECT DATA_AJUSTE FROM ESTOQUE_PRODUTOS 
    WHERE FILIAL = @NOME_FILIAL AND DATA_AJUSTE IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY DATA_AJUSTE)

    UPDATE ESTOQUE_PRODUTOS SET DATA_AJUSTE = '20190309'
    WHERE FILIAL = @NOME_FILIAL AND DATA_AJUSTE IS NOT NULL

    DELETE FROM LJ_ETL_REPOSITORIO WHERE ID_ETL_TIPO='171'
    AND FILTRO LIKE '%' + @NOME_FILIAL + '%'

    PRINT @DATA_AJUSTE

UPDATE LJ_ETL_ARQUIVO SET PROCESSADO = '1'
WHERE ID_ETL_TIPO = '6'
AND CODIGO_FILIAL = @CODIGO_FILIAL
```

O problema é que nem sempre os dados na coluna DATA _AJUSTE serão os mesmos.... Agradeço muito se puderem me ajudar....

Comment: Tirar um back-up da tabela, alterar como quiser, voltar o back-up ao final de tudo. Ou não é isso o que quis dizer?

Comment: Não consigo fazer isso pois o banco se comunica com outro, na hora de voltar o bkp com certeza vai dar problema....

Comment: por que não coloca numa tabela temporária?

Comment: Salvar o conteudo em outra coluna !? Não sei se entendi o problema.

Comment: Uma possibilidade é fazer todas as alterações dentro de uma transação e ao final dar um ROLLBACK no lugar de um COMMIT.